# How can i relate two excel records using angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to relate to xlsx file records using angular based on their id . To make it more clear :

I have this example :

- Case 1

[image]

- Case 2

[image]

**Edit:**

I dont mean a merge , what i mean is that i want to get all data of id in case that have same id in case 1

Comment: "I want to relate to xlsx file records"? Do you want to compare the files?

Comment: yes i want to see if this file contain the same id so i will merge them

Comment: You will have to use some kind of excel-parsing library for this and then may be a different excel-creating library to create a merged excel file. However I would strongly recommend doing it in Angular. Excel parsing can turn seriously heavy task for browser. This should be done on the server-side

Comment: As suggested by @SaurabhTiwari. The file processing task should always be done at server side. As you stated that you''ll need to merge these records, for that generate new file on server and send that to client via response. This new file can be replaced with old excel file.

Comment: i want to get all data in case 2 that have same id in case 1. That what i mean.. i don't mean a merge

Answer (score 0):

The excel processing on client side can be a very heavy task, which might result in unresponsive pages and crashes.

The file processing task should always be done at server side. As you stated that you''ll need to merge these records, for that generate new file on server and send that to client via response. This new file can be replaced with old excel file.

If you still need to do as you mentioned, IMO `node-xlsx` is the way to go. It provides flexible ways to parse excel.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx

Comment: is there any demo ?

Comment: you can read documentation for the above library. either on NPM or on github.